# How to get particular column data from the CSV?

Tags: magento2, csv

I have read the data from the CSV

```
$data = $fileCsv->getData($file);
foreach ($data as $row => $data) {
    if ($row > 0) {
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

I have got the content only the one column that is Customer Email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please try following way so you get email column data

```
 <?php
$file = fopen('example.csv', 'r');
$c = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
//$line is an array of the csv elements
    $c++;
    if($c == 1){
        continue;
    }
    echo $line[3]; // Here 3 is my column that contain email
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey For this I am getting the column name. How to get Data from the column name

Comment: @Divya please check my update answer.Now we skip column name.